# How to update values of particular keys efficiently

Tags: replacement, dataset, associations

Say I have a list of `Association`,

```
SeedRandom[45]
test = Association[Table[i -> RandomInteger[30], {i, 6}]]
```

> <|1 -> 18, 2 -> 19, 3 -> 12, 4 -> 28, 5 -> 22, 6 -> 3|>

How to efficiently **update** the values according to new rules/counts?
I tried

```
AssociateTo[test, -Counts[{2, 1, 2, 6}]]
```

> <|1 -> -1, 2 -> -2, 3 -> 12, 4 -> 28, 5 -> 22, 6 -> -1|>

which is obvisoult not what I want. Desired result is

> <|1 -> 17, 2 -> 17, 3 -> 12, 4 -> 28, 5 -> 22, 6 -> 2|>

That is, to reduce the value of relevant keys by the number of counts.

I used `-Counts[]` hope it `add to` the old values, but it was obviously the wrong thing to use here.

Apart from setting up long winded rules to locate each key and change its value individually, I am sure there are more efficient ways to hand this?

I have **long** `Association` and needs to update quickly (efficiently).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking to merge your two associations. Use [`Merge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html), and use `Total` to combine the paired up values from the two associations to sum them:

```
Merge[{test, -Counts[{2, 1, 2, 6}]}, Total]

(* Out: <|1 -> 17, 2 -> 17, 3 -> 12, 4 -> 28, 5 -> 22, 6 -> 2|> *)
```

To check how this works, take a look at the result of the plain combination, i.e. `Merge[{test, -Counts[{2, 1, 2, 6}]}, Identity]`.

Comment: I checked a lot of related syntax and I didn't see this! Thanks. It's exactly what I need!

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Glad it helps!